# How to use Pug to convert a directory of Markdown files into HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm starting to use Pug templating

I've got a directory with some markdown files that I'd like to turn into HTML pages

```
legal/
    privacy-policy.md
    refund-policy.md
    terms-of-service.md
```

So far, I've thought to place a `.pug` file alongside each

```
legal/
    privacy-policy.md
  + privacy-policy.pug
    refund-policy.md
  + refund-policy.pug
    terms-of-service.md
  + terms-of-service.pug
```

The `.pug` files are all very similar, "boilerplatey" -- they extend the same template:

```
extends ../layout.pug

block lead
  title Privacy Policy

block content
  .content
    include:markdown-it(linkify) privacy-policy.md
```

This works for now, but it clearly doesn't scale

**How can I do better than this?** What's the best way to iterate the `.pug` boilerplate over each markdown file in the directory?

Comment: I wonder if a frontmatter section in each markdown could announce the `title` to the pug template? Still not sure of a decent way to go about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd move all the code to do this back into the route (i.e. into node.js itself), where you have access to the [fs file system library](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

To list all the documents do something like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){

  var folder = 'legal';
  var fs= require('fs');
  var fileList = [];

  fs.readdir(folder, function(err, files){
    files.forEach(function(file){
      fileList.push(file);
    });
  })

  res.render('directory', {"files": fileList});

}
```

Then to read a file in use a url parameter:

```
router.get('/:fileName', function(req, res){

  var fileName = 'legal/' + req.params.fileName + '.md';
  var fs= require('fs');

  fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    res.render('contract', {"title": req.params.fileName, "text": data});


});
```

In your pug template for the contracts just output the variable as rendered using interpolation:

```
!{text}
```

You could also get fancy with the title using something like [SugarJS titleize](https://sugarjs.com/docs/#/String/titleize) which will dynamically create a proper title from the file name.

Answer (score 0):

With just one Pug, this is not feasible. At least it didn't work out for me.
The easiest way to use Pug to convert a directory of Markdown files into HTML pages is to connect the [MdPugToHtml] converter to your project (https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-pug-to-html ). It massively converts Markdown to html. Moreover, it is possible to use Pug templates, but you can use them without templates.

The converter has various settings and can be used both in the CLI command line and has an API for use in applications.

There is detailed documentation on the MdPugToHtml converter in [English](https://github.com/injashkin/md-pug-to-html/blob/main/README.md) and [Russian](https://github.com/injashkin/md-pug-to-html/blob/main/README.ru.md) languages.

The converter can also be used independently. You can manually convert entire directories with Markdown files. The conversion is performed in the terminal with just one command:

```
npx md-pug-to-html /home/content
```

where:

- `npx` is an npm command that installs md-pug-to-html at the first launch, and then launches the md-pug-to-html converter.
- `/home/content` is the directory with your Markdown files. You may have another one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).